# Count number of elements in a list of lists

Tags: algorithm, list, ocaml, sml

I've to adapt an existing code in Standard ML and I'm facing a problem right now.

I've got a function which is returning me a list of elements (let's call them Nodes (or Worlds))

```
val worlds = listNodes()
```

And for each `world` I've got a function `fun listSuccessors w r` which is returning the number of successors for each world.

My question is : How to obtain the number of successors globally ?

In pseudo code, I would like something like this :

```
worlds <--  listNodes ()
solution  <-- 0

foreach w in worlds do 
     solution <-- solution + (length (listSuccessors w))
end foreach

return solution
```

But I unfortunately have no idea how to do this :/

Here are the existing functions :

```
fun listSuccessors w r =
        let
            val succs =
                case Dynarraydict.get (nodes, Node.getId w)
                    of ROOT (_, _, succs) => succs
                     | _ => Exn.unexpArg "Nodestore.listSuccessors.succs"
        in
            List.mapPartial (fn (n, r', _) => if r = r' then SOME (getNode n) else NONE) succs
        end
```

---

```
fun listNodes () = Dynarraydict.foldr (fn (_, ROOT item, ys) => (#1 item)::ys | (_, _, ys) => ys) nil nodes
```

Thanks in advance for your help :/ I'm a total beginner in Standard ML unfortunately, so it's quite complicated to understand how to manipulate list of lists. :/

Comment: to be sure I catch well : you have a list of lists of "simple" elements. And you would like to get the total amount of "simple" elements ?

Comment: Well it's more like : I've got a list of element N, and each N as a list inside (successors)) and I want to know how many successors there is in the main list (so the sum of successors for each element N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints : sum the size of the lists using List.fold and List.length.
In 1 single line you should be able to implement your pseudocode.
It should be some thing like :

```
List.fold (fun acc x -> acc+List.length x) 0 your_list_of_list.
```

Comment: I know that it's probably 2 functions to use in the standard functions, but I don't know at all this language, I'm just adapting a function in a "state-of-the art" program in order to compare it with something that I created from scratch in C :/ 

So if you could provide this line, I would make me win a lot of time in the documentation :/

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this looks like homework in spite of the comment, because it is a typical exercise, and a FP idiom.

A standard solution in ML (sic) is a recursive function where the parameters act as storage to sum something up or to collect some list. Other parameter(s) (the input data) diminish at every step and when empty cause the termination of the recursion.

This idiom serves the purpose to minimize the use of mutable state in the program.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well it's not homework, my main goal is I want to compare results between 2 programs. I create one from scratch in C, and I want to modify the "state-of-the-art" in Standard ML to get a "comparable output". But I don't know Standard ML and I unfortunately don't have time to go completely through this language :/

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail Okay, I delete my proposal, because I know ocaml but the SML syntax is so different I don't want to bother too much with it... oops, got a plus for it.